# pipe email hosted at Amazon SES to ec2 hosted php script

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I have a website hosted on an amazon ec2 and I have the websites email address hosted at amazon SES, we also use amazon workmail to access the emails and send out emails. However now what we would like to do is pipe all email sent to our websites email address into a php mysql script (we are building a communication management system).

However I can not find any suggestions or documentation on how I would be able to forward emails received into the aws workmail inbox to an external hosted php file?

I know I need to setup a sns but not sure how to write it. also I need to make sure that attachments also come over.

Answer (score 0):

You could deliver mail with SES to an Amazon S3 bucket. Then grant your "php mysql script" access. The official [SES Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html) could help you:

[Amazon SES Email-Receiving Concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html) (search for "S3 action")

[View the Received Email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-view.html)

It works with attachments and without SNS.